# Duplicate HTML in jQuery into a BootStrap Modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, traversal

The function below is called after an icon is clicked, which creates a modal. During the function, I traverse up the DOM, grab a HTML canvas and display it in the modal. The problem I am having is that it is removing the HTML I grab initially, I want it to be duplicated. Can anyone shed some light on this?

JS:

```
$('#chartModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
  console.log('yeppp');
  // Button that triggered the modal
  const button = $(event.relatedTarget)
  // Get corresponding chart's HTML
  const chart = button.parent().next()[0]
  var modal = $(this)
  // Update modal's content with the corresponding chart
  modal.find('.modal-body').html(chart)
})
```

Regards,
James.

Comment: `modal.find('.modal-body').html(chart.clone() ); ` perhaps?

Comment: @Snowmonkey should be rather `$(chart).clone()` isn't it? As `button.parent().next()[0]` returns a node, not a jQuery object.

Comment: @Snowmonkey throws 'chart.clone is not a function'

Comment: @dferenc Is there any way to duplicate a node in jQuery?

Comment: Sure there is: https://api.jquery.com/clone/

Comment: out of curiousity, why are you setting chart to a const? and @dferenc, button is a jQuery-wrapped object, as is the parent() call, as is the next(). Oh, but you're right -- next()[0] returns the el itself. Good call. I would try `console.log(chart);` out of curiousity.

Comment: @Snowmonkey Please note `[0]` at the end of the line. `.next()` returns a jQuery object, but `.next()[0]` is simply the first element of the jQuery collection, which is a node.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using jQuery, you can use the [`.clone()`](https://api.jquery.com/clone/) method like so:

```
$('#chartModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
    // Button that triggered the modal
    var button = $(event.relatedTarget);
    // Get corresponding chart's HTML
    // "chart" is a plain node here
    var chart = button.parent().next()[0];
    var modal = $(this);
    // Update modal's content with the corresponding chart
    modal.find('.modal-body').html($(chart).clone());
})

// OR 

$('#chartModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
    // Button that triggered the modal
    var button = $(event.relatedTarget);
    // Get corresponding chart's HTML
    // "chart" is now a jQuery object
    var chart = button.parent().next();
    var modal = $(this);
    // Update modal's content with the corresponding chart
    modal.find('.modal-body').html(chart.clone());
})
```

Comment: @JamesBarrett I just have tested it again, and this seems to be working to me. What do you see in the console?

Comment: I just deleted my comment because I realized some inconsistencies in the DOM with .html() and .clone(). So my original code snippet takes a parent div element with it (which I actually need, hence why the canvas was showing in the modal!): https://gyazo.com/b5b1c355f7c97b654914ada8fd27bbb7 Your solution didn't work in my scenario as the parent div was not taken with it: https://gyazo.com/32de63dd81b6a8d32f8d995b258c2983?token=dca96de6b206c56abdef71add0c0fdb1  My question is: Why did .html() take a parent and .clone() didn't?

Comment: Just to get to the same page, could you please include the outline of your relevant html into the question? Just because, your

Answer (score 0):

Your current code snippet seems overly complicated in my opinion.

Here's a different solution that might be easier to follow:

HTML:

```
...
<canvas class="one-of-my-charts"></canvas>
...
```

JS:

```
$('.one-of-my-charts').click(function(e) {

    $('#the-chart-modal').html(e.target);

    $('#the-chart-modal').modal('show');

});
```